# PHP get previous page url after redirect

Tags: php

I want to have a navigation bar that tells the user where they just came from.
Example: Homepage -> Post

But if they are in their posts manager and click on a post, I want it to say
Posts manager -> Post

I read that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not good enough to get the full url so that's not useful as I want the navigation bar all clickable

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Will they only come from internal pages?

Comment: if the `HTTP_REFERER` not enougth, use javascript on client side to store the complete URL (with Hash tags, and more) bevore unload.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe what you want is called [breadcrumbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29).

What to use for navigation chain storage is actually up to you. You might use even $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] if you want, but that'd be unreliable as it's client-side. Usual way to store such chain is actual URI or session.

For example, you have such URI: http://www.example.com/post_manager/post

Then you can iterate through `explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])` to get each step.

That's basic explanation to guide you to a right direction. You can google alot of samples and snippets using keyword `breadcrumbs`.

On the topic of saving last visited location (the way to determine wether abonent came from manager or homepage): you can use session's variables to do that. Here's an example:

This way you can set a variable on your homepage:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['previous_location'] = 'homepage';
?>
```

And then you just access it from another page:

```
<?php
    $previous_location = $_SESSION['previous_location'];
?>
```

It's important to set [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) in your PHP configuration file or your sessions might get lost.

Comment: yeah the only problem is how to make it dynamically change from homepage to posts manager depending where you clicked on the post from?

Comment: Same way you decide what to display (homepage or manager). I believe it depends on some get/post variable or part of URI?

Comment: how can I check where the post was clicked from (homepage or from post manager)?

Comment: You can store last visited location in user's session. I'll update my answer with some specifics.

Comment: An issue with doing it this way is it assumes the user only has one tab open with the site. If they have multiple tabs open with the site, anyone one of them could be be the most recently visited and it or any of the others could result in the next page call... resulting in some very demented looking navigation flows. Much better to use referrer and check it against a list of visited pages.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it on the client side if you use the Javascript [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) property. However, a better solution may be to use the global session array.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])) {
    $_SESSION['referrer'] = $current_uri;
} else {
    $previous_uri = $_SESSION['referrer'];
    $_SESSION['referrer'] = $current_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution IMO is to save the location into session, every time the user goes to a 'meaningful' page (that you want to be able to navigate back to via this feature),  then simply use this array of, say, last 2 visited pages to pull up all the information.   Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['user_interactions'][] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    // get previous
    $previous_page = end($_SESSION['user_interactions']);

    // list all user interactions
    foreach($_SESSION['user_interactions'] as $key => $value){
        echo $value;
        if(count($_SESSION['user_interactions'])-1 != $key) echo ">";

    }
?>
```